# Send multiple sensor value to python server

Tags: python, sockets, arduino, esp8266

I'm a new in python and IoT stuff. I want to send humidity and temperature value with DHT11 that attached to my ESP8266 to python server but, for a reason I want humid and temp are printed on different variable. e.g 2 variables. I read about splitting the string after received, but I still cannot figure it out.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <dht.h>

WiFiClient client;
dht DHT;

client.print("Temp: " + String(DHT.temperature, 0) + " °C");
client.print("Humid: " + String(DHT.humidity, 0) + "%");
```

Python (this is my expectation):

```
while True:
    try:
        humid, temp = conn.recv(2048).decode("utf-8")
        print(humid)
        print(temp)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Here's the output. The odd line is temp, and the even line is humid
[image]

If there are any better solution, please let me know. Sorry for my language, english is not my main language

Comment: what does it do right now? What doe humid and temp print out?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I already edit it

Comment: So what is the problem then? Sorry if I'm not understanding your problem correctly but you have 2 separate variables now right?

Answer (score 0):

try this code instead:

```
while True:
try:
    humid, temp = conn.recv(2048).decode("utf-8").split("\n")
    print(humid)
    print(temp)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    break
```